# How can I run a Libgdx eclipse project in AIDE on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, aide-ide

I would like to run and compile my Libgdx game project in AIDE on Android, but I don't quite know how to do it. Should I edit .classpath file, move jars to different directory or maybe something else? 
Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Eclipse project you can just open the android project in AIDE and it will work.
Besides, the latest version of AIDE contains sample libgdx tutorials so you can also build from there or inspect those .classpath settings, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install gradle from : http://download.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/gradle/ 
and try importing